# update creative in existing ad group

Tags: facebook, facebook-ads-api, adgroup

We are trying to update\replace the creative of existing adgroup with no success.
According to the documentation is supported:
Updating and deleting ad groups

***Using the ad group ID, you can update the following fields in an ad group:
name
max_bid
adgroup_status
bid_type
targeting
creative***

We pass a new creative id to the adgroup using the graph api , but nothing happens.

How can we update the creative of an existing adgroup?

Found a solution, you can replace the creative but you can't edit an existing creative.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are only able to rename the creative and/or change the creative's run status. Other elements of the creative cannot be updated.

The AdCreative object is designed to help devs reuse the same creative across multiple adgroups. They have decided to lock it down so it cannot be edited after creation so that clients do not accidentally change the creative of 1,000s of ads without directly editing those ads. The concern is that people may forget which ads a creative is used in and they may end up editing the creative of an ad they don't intend to change.

In order to update let's say the creative's link_url, you need to post to `graph.facebook.com/{adgroup-id}` with a parameter `creative` and the value `{link_url:"your_new_url}`. New creative will be cloned from the old one, the new link url will be set, and the new creative ID will be assigned to the ad group.

At least this works at the moment :)