# Add "url_tags" to existing Ad creatives part of Ad-Group

Tags: facebook-ads-api

What is the best way to add "url_tags" to Ad creatives that have already been added to an existing Ad-Group, when the Ad is already live?

I understand that an Ad creative cannot be updated once it is live. This answer suggested a solution [update creative in existing ad group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8149684/update-creative-in-existing-ad-group) , but it doesn't seem to work anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can update an existing adgroup's creative by creating a new adcreative and then update the adgroup with the new adcreative id:

1. Create a new ad creative with your url_tags (in this example, "key=val"):

   curl \
   -F "type=27" \
   -F "object_id=object_id" \
   -F "story_id=story_id" \
   -F "url_tags=key=val" \
   -F "access_token=*_*" \
   "https://graph.facebook.com/act_12134567/adcreatives"
2. Update your adgroup with the new adcreative id:

   curl  \
   -F "creative={'creative_id':new_adcreative_id}" \
   -F "access_token=*_*"  \
   "https://graph.facebook.com/adgroup_id"